# Required Field validation not shown to the user

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

All the validations work fine in my web form, except the required field validations. When the user enter the submit button the data will be saved in the table, even if there're some missing fields. I want to fix that so the user can't submit if the textbox is empty. I tried to add the page.isvalid but still it is not working. Please can someone help me

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace RegistrationForm5
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=DESKTOP-20J5J59;Initial Catalog=RegistrationWebForm1;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into RegistrationWebForm1" + "(Title, Name, ID, Email, Mobile, Major, Note)values(@TxtTitle, @TxtName, @TxtID, @TxtEmail, @TxtMobile, @LstMajor, @TxtNote)", con);


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtTitle", TxtTitle.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtName", TxtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtID", TxtID.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtEmail", TxtEmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtMobile", TxtMobile.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LstMajor", LstMajor.SelectedItem.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtNote", TxtNote.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label1.Text = "Your request has been submitted successfully";

                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                Label1.Text = "Please fill the empty fileds";

            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="RegistrationForm5.Registration" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            margin-right: 2px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 101px;
            height: 144px;
        }
        body {
            
            background-size:cover;
            background-color:lightgrey
            
            
             }
        .top-style{
            background-color:darkslategrey;
            height: 78px;
           
        }
        .titl{
            text-align:center;
            color:beige;
                
            font-size:26px;

        }
        .auto-style28 {
            width: 101px;
            height: 62px;
        }
        .auto-style29 {
            height: 62px;
        }
        .auto-style30 {
            width: 101px;
            height: 49px;
        }
        .auto-style31 {
            width: 101px;
            height: 55px;
        }
        .auto-style32 {
            height: 55px;
        }
        .auto-style37 {
            height: 40px;
        }
        .auto-style38 {
            width: 101px;
            height: 40px;
        }
        .auto-style39 {
            width: 101px;
            height: 54px;
        }
        .auto-style40 {
            height: 54px;
        }
        .auto-style42 {
            height: 46px;
        }
        .auto-style43 {
            width: 101px;
            height: 46px;
        }
        .auto-style44 {
            height: 144px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top-style" >
        <br />
        <p class="titl">Registration form</p>
    </div>
    
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <div>
            <table align="center" class="auto-style1">
               
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style30">Title: </td>
                    <td class="auto-style30">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTitle" runat="server"  placeholder="Title" Width="288px"></asp:TextBox>

                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate ="TxtTitle" ErrorMessage="Enter Title" InitialValue="Enter Title"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style31">Name:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style32">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server" placeholder="Full name" Width="288px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate ="TxtName" ErrorMessage="Enter your name" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Enter your name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style28">ID:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style29">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtID" runat="server" placeholder="201600000" Width="288px" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate ="TxtID" ErrorMessage="Enter your ID" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Enter your ID"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                        <br />

                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter 9 numbers" ControlToValidate="TxtID" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\d{9}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style39">E-mail:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style40">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmail" runat="server" placeholder="name@example.com" Width="288px" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>

                        <br />

                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtEmail" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate ="TxtEmail" ErrorMessage="Enter your email" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Enter your email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style38">Mobile No:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style37">
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtMobile" runat="server" placeholder="966500000000" Width="288px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate ="TxtMobile" ErrorMessage="Enter your Mobile number" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Enter your mobile number"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtMobile" ErrorMessage="invalid mobile number" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\d{12}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style43">Major:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style42">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="LstMajor" runat="server" Height="28px" Width="288px">
                            <asp:ListItem>Select Option</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Accounting</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Architecture</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Business Administration</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Computer Science</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Computer Engineering</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Civil Engineering</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Electrical Engineering</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Finance</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Graphic Design</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Human Resource Management</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Information Technology</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Interior Design</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Law</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Mchanical Engineering</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Managment Information System</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Software Engineering</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>

                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate ="LstMajor" ErrorMessage="Select a major" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select a major"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">Note:</td>
                    <td class="auto-style44">
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtNote" placeholder="Add More Information..." runat="server" Width="288px" Height="124px" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="auto-style1"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" Font-Size="Medium" Height="36px" Width="110px" OnClientClick=" return confirm(Your request has been submitted successfully" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might need to add some like `if (Page.IsValid)` in your `Button1_Click`. It's always a good idea to do another valiation check server-side, not just client-side

Comment: I did but still it is not working

Comment: Is your placeholder text testing positive as if the field was given data?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure that I understood what you mean, but everything works fine like if I have a form without required validation

Comment: thank you all it works now, I used  "required="required"" instead of required field validation

Comment: Not related to your problem but [Can with stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)